# Suspending iAd display in a container view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

This is not an iAd question as much as it is a code design and view controller communication question.

My app's root view controller is a container view controller that consists of two things:

- A child content view controller
- An ADBannerView subview that appears and disappears as it receives data from the iAds server

Basically, this container view controller is just a wrapper for the real view controllers, and its purpose is to manage the display and layout resizing as ads appear and disappear. (It's a direct rip of the [ContainerBanner sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)).

I have a conundrum, however. Apple's best practice for iAd display states:

> If the user navigates from a screen of content with a banner view to a screen that does not have a banner view, and you expect them to be on that screen for a long period of time, remove the banner view from the view hierarchy, set its delegate to nil and release it before transitioning to the new screen of content. More generally, avoid keeping a banner view around when it is invisible to the user.

That means when some child view controller takes over the entire screen for a while, I need to send a message to the container view controller to suspend ad display.

**What's the most elegant way to accomplish this?**

I'm getting tripped up because this communication has to traverse a few levels up the view controller hierarchy, which makes delegation and blocks a not-very-good solution.

The only solution I can think of is to have the child view controller post a notification, which the container view controller is listening to and responds by suspending/resuming ad display. I want to know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Do you want the ad banner to be displayed in all of your view controller or just the main one?

Comment: It's not about visually displaying or not displaying the ad banner because presenting a VC modally will cover up the ad banner. What I want to do is suspend the ads when a modally-presented VC covers up the ad banner for a long time.